# how to point to functions in different calsses

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i wrote a program for a pic32mx575f512h in C++. the processor has 6 uarts and the program routes the uart packets from one to another. the program is written using two generic classes. a receive class and a send class. when the objects for these classes are declared a struct with settings is handed to them to make them unique.

to ease interconnecting these objects the receive class is handed an array of send class pointers. when a message arrives say for uart "one" on any of the other uarts the receive class calls the appropriate send class from the array by using the address as the array index. for example:
    send_pointer[received_address]->data_put()...
the code is tested and works well.

now i need to expand the code further to add debugging through usb. the usb stack is taken care of i just need a way to pass data from the receive class to the send class including a function for the usb. where i'm struggling is that the usb send handler is completely different from the the uart send class. i would like to add another member to the array of send pointers but that's not possible. i've tried making an array of function pointers but C++ won't allow storing the member of a class in a function pointer.

is there another way i can do this so i can still use the address as an index of where the message needs to go?

Comment: Event pattern perhaps?

Comment: Ifeelsorryforyoubecausyourshiftkeyisasbrokenasmyspacebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute methods of a class, you either need an instance, or the method has to be declared as static.

Search the internet for "c++ FAQ pointer to member function".

You may need to redesign you program or use a Factory Design pattern.